# Matlab Basic fitting line regression error

Tags: matlab

Hi im trying to fit a line of best fit/R2 value on my graph. im plotting date/time (x-axis) against an arbitrary value (context agnostic) and when trying to do it through the basic fitting tools in the figure information it is greyed out. If i graph another column against the original arbitrary value column that isn't time it works fine? im not sure why? Attached photos. The column date time is recognised as datetime by matlab (yyyy,dd,mm hh:mm:ss) for example: 2021-01-10 22:30:45. For context i am trying to analyse time between a few hours and linear regression it. the other axis (y-axis) is just values between 0.4- 0.9 slowly increasing. Any help would be muchly appreciated

[image: visable graph]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If it works when graphing against a column that is not datetime, it may be the format that is preventing basic fitting. You could consider converting your datetime values to Unix timestamps. Then you can plot your Unix timestamp against your second column and [replace the datetime axis labels](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/change-tick-marks-and-tick-labels-of-graph-1.html).